# After rake db:migrate undefined symbol rb_str2cstr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, db2, database-migration

After hours of finding and correcting the installation mistakes i finally succeeded while executing sudo rails g scaffold etc

When it comes to the moment to finally migrate it, i get this mistake but I'm not quite sure what it means so i dunno how to correct it! Please help!

$ rake db:migrate
/usr/local/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ibm_db-2.5.10/lib/ibm_db.so: undefined symbol: rb_str2cstr

Comment: can you please provide the rails g scaffold that you ran exactly.  I've had issues with reserved words in the past

Comment: $ sudo rails g scaffold clientes id_cliente:integer nom_cliente:string ap_cliente:string rfc_cliente:string dom_cliente:string
Plural version of the model detected, using singularized version. Override with --force-plural.
      invoke  active_record
Another migration is already named create_clientes: /home/tepucheritos/Downloads/nombre_proyecto/db/migrate/20131202195558_create_clientes.rb
$ rake db:migrate
/usr/local/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ibm_db-2.5.10/lib/ibm_db.so: undefined symbol: rb_str2cstr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) cd .../gems/ibm_db-2.5.11/ext
2) replace "if( RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/)" with "if(
RUBY_VERSION =~ /2.0/)" in extconf.rb
3) ruby extconf.rb
4) make && cp ibm_db.so ../lib/

Worked for me

Source: https://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29728&group_id=2361&atid=9176